# Как из ветки main подтянуть изменение в другую ветку

Tags: git, github

У меня есть 2 ветки. Main - главная, wr - вторая ветка. В ветке wr я создал новый файл и закомитил, после залил все изменения в ветку main. После я перешел в ветку main и удалил этот файл, в ветке main удалился, но после перехода в ветку wr файл там остался. Я попробовал команду `git pull`, которая синхронизирует данные, но она не помогла. Что в этом случае делать?

Comment: смержить ветку мейн в вр

Comment: пулл просто получает обновления ветки из центрального репозитория в предложении что другие участники проекта также могли что-то туда закоммитить

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Comment: `git checkout main` + `git merge wr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто заберите изменения из main

```
git merge main
```